# Restarting Dev Server in Vue/Vite

Tags: vue.js, npm, vite

I have created a new Vite project following the guide on https://vitejs.dev/guide/. I have not even touched the files. Then my pc restarted (windows updates ...) and now, I can not restart the dev server. When I type npm run dev, it gives me the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\(((PATH)))Codes\vue\vite\vite-3/package.json
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\name\Documents\name\Codes\vue\vite\vite-3\package.json'       
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do, can anyone please help?

Comment: The error suggests that you're in C:\Users\sabin\Documents\corinna\Codes\vue\vite\vite-3\ folder when you run `npm run dev`, and it's not a folder with project root, there should be package.json file. Make sure you do it the right way. At this point may be a basic user-level problem with command line, not tied to Vue. That you closed a window with command line and reopened with another working directory is the obvious difference between PC reboots.

Comment: Did you look if that file was at that directory? Or at some other directory? Did you try just recreating it, since you said this was brand new anyways?